# Link a Wordpress container to MariaDB container

Tags: wordpress, docker, networking, docker-compose, mariadb

I have 3 Docker containers (WordPress+PHP, MariaDB and Nginx) in my Docker Compose file. I can connect to `localhost`, but WordPress then tells me it can't connect to a database. This suggests to me that, while WordPress can reach Nginx, it can't reach MariaDB.

Opening a shell in the WordPress container and trying to connect manually gives an error:

```
$ mysql -u root -p123456789 -h mariadb base -P 3306
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.28.0.2' (115)
```

My MariaDB gets set up with this script:

```bash
if [ ! -d "/var/lib/mysql/mysql" ]; then
    mysql_install_db \
    --user=mysql \
    --datadir=/var/lib/mysql  \
    --port=3306 \
    --socket=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock \
    --bind_address=* > /dev/null 2>&1

    service mysql start

    mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${SQL_DATABASE}\`;"
    sleep 1

    mysql -e "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS \`${SQL_USER}\`@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 
    '${SQL_PASSWORD}';"
    sleep 1

    mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`${SQL_DATABASE}\`.* TO 
    \`${SQL_USER}\`@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${SQL_PASSWORD}';"
    sleep 1

    mysql -e "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}';"
    sleep 1


    mysql -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" -u root -p"$SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
    sleep 1

    mysqladmin --user=root --password=$SQL_ROOT_PASSWORD shutdown

    echo "Configuration finished."
else
    echo "Database doesn't exist."
fi

exec mysqld_safe
```

Opening a shell on my MariaDB container, everything seems good. I can connect to my database with the same command and credentials I used above.

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    networks:
      - inception
    build:
      context: requirements/mariadb/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
    networks:
      - inception
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    build: 
      context: requirements/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    restart: on-failure
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
    networks:
      - inception
    build: 
      context: requirements/wordpress
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      mariadb:
        condition: service_started
    restart: on-failure
    expose: 
      - "9000"

volumes:
  mariadb:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none' 
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/${HOME}/Desktop/Inception/mariadb'
  wordpress:
    driver: local 
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/${HOME}/Desktop/Inception/wordpress'

networks:
  inception:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Everything you have done in your script can be achieved with the standard [Docker Official Image of MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) using the plain `$MARIADB_...` variables (except in a working way).

Comment: The purpose is to doing all the things myself, I don't want to use an image already done and do not understand where my error come from

Comment: check the container error logs then. And use `set -x -v` for debugging what the script actually does.

Comment: All the logs are fine, the wordpress installation work well and mysql too...